# RavenDB query alias in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, ravendb, querydsl

I'm sure I'm missing the glaringly obvious, but I can't figure out what the "Q"-prefixed types are supposed to be, or how to resolve them. Basically, all over the Java documentation, QSomething classes are used, yet I can't find an explanation what they really are, how the prefix works, or how they are resolved.
Even at the very beginning, [here](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/java/start/getting-started), `QCategory c = QCategory.category;` is used without any pointers as to how those Q-prefixed types are resolved. Predictably, when I try to create an object according to that syntax logic, I get "[abc] cannot be resolved to a type". So if someone could shed some light on that "mystical" Qsometype stuff, I'd be very grateful.

Edit: I'm *not* currently using Maven for my Eclipse setup (the tutorial mentions Maven pom) 
Is this impossible without using Maven ? 
I've investigated some more and I understand the Q-classes are auto-generated by QueryDSL and Maven. My project type in Eclipse is dynamic web, and I'm not sure I want to/should convert this to a Maven project. In fact, I'm not even sure that would solve my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are auto generated classes, if you setup using Maven, it just works.
The configuration entry for this is `<processor>net.ravendb.querydsl.RavenDBAnnotationProcessor</processor>`

This is using `QueryDSL` to generate the query classes.

The explanation in the docs is:

> Please note that plugins section contains
>   `net.ravendb.querydsl.RavenDBAnnotationProcessor`. As Java does not have
>   LINQ, all definitions of indexes/transformers must be created using
>   strings. Alternatively, you can use the Studio to create
>   indexes/transformers, yet you can also use QueryDSL for strongly-typed
>   querying. In order to use QueryDSL you have to mark your entities with
>   `@QueryEntity` annotation and enable code generation in pom.xml.

You can generate this manually, see http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.7.3/reference/html/ch03s02.html

Comment: Ayende, thanks for your help ! I did decide to "mavenise" my project after all, and it does indeed work. I was a bit reluctant to switch over, fearing that something awful might happen to the project once Eclipse automagically turned it into a Maven project. It didn't.